# Find a r.v. for a transformation of a compound poisson process

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-process

Consider a compound Poisson process
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N_t}X_i$$
where $N_t$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda_1$ and $X_i$ i.i.d. with  cumulative distribution function $F(.)$ so that mean and variance are both finite.

Now I need to find another r.v. $Z_j$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{M_t} Z_j= \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} X_i$$
where $M_t$ is another poisson process defined on the same $t$ with rate $\lambda_2$.

$Z_j$ should be i.i.d. with mean and variance finite. Does $Z_j$ exist? If so, how much information can we figure out about its cdf ?

Thx here for any helping hand.